# Duvida API Camera nas Apps Android DubsMash, Vine e Musical.ly

Tags: android, app, lollipop

Tenho ultimamente trabalhado com a API `MediaRecorder` de Android para fazer capturas de video, mas deparo-me com um problema comum em que existe um grande delay na hora de começar a gravar um video.

A minha intenção é fazer uma aplicação em que pode se gravar um video fazendo pause sem que haja um grande delay na hora de voltar a gravar.

Mas com o `MediaRecorder` isso não é possível.

Ou seja, quero fazer uma aplicação de gravação de video estilo app do Vine, em que a gravação é feita quando o utilizador esta pressionando o ecrã e quando o mesmo tira o dedo do ecrã,a gravação entra em pause.

Como posso resolver essa situação?

Comment: Ola Elizeu Seja bem vindo ao Stack OverFlow Português. Não estou conseguindo entender seu problema, você poderia editar a pergunta e esclarecer ela um pouco mais? Para editar clique no botão 'editar', sugiro que faça um [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) também para aprender mais sobre o site.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Para que a comunidade possa te ajudar, é importante que se explique detalhadamente o seu problema.

Sugiro que leia os artigos: [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e [como realizar uma pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ou seja, quero fazer uma aplicação de gravacao de video estilo app do Vine, em que a gravaçao é feita quando o utilizador esta pressionando o ecrã e quando o mesmo tira o dedo do ecrã,a gravação entra em pause.